# Dismiss multiple ViewControllers together when using current context as presentation style

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I'm creating an application where I place a view controller ontop of another with

> Presentation: current context

But when I'm trying to dismiss the screen by dragging the top towards the bottom the view does not disappear.

I've also tried to add a button to make it dismiss but that doesn't work either.

```
@IBAction func dis(_ sender: Any) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

So, how can I dismiss both views when dragging the top one down when it uses "current context" as presentation style?

I'm using "current context" because the previous screen should never be displayed again. And instead of dragging down both, I would like to drag down just one to make both of them disappear. But it does not seem to work as expected.

Comment: “ I'm using "current context" because the previous screen should never be displayed again.” But that is not at all what current context presentation means. You are just shooting yourself in the foot with this. If you want drag to dismiss, use automatic.

Comment: @matt Alright, thanks. 

Do you have any idea how I can dismiss the "first" view when navigating to another view controller?

Comment: @matt Like lets say I'm navigating from A to B (This is the one I want to hide) and then navigate to C. 

So when I navigate to C I would like to "hide/remove" view controller B. Is this even possible? lol

Comment: Yes it is. But it isn't what you asked. You've proposed an "x-y" question. You have a problem "x", but instead of asking about it, you've imagined a solution "y" that doesn't work, and now your question is about "y", which was the wrong road to go down in the first place.

Comment: @matt Well, I've no idea how I should structure this question up. Since I'm not even sure what I need. I do know how I want the result to be, but not what to use and where to use it in this case.

Comment: Well, the question should not have been about dismissing something in current context style. It should be about what you said in your comment: "I'm navigating from A to B (This is the one I want to hide) and then navigate to C. So when I navigate to C I would like to "hide/remove" view controller B". There are lots of ways to do that; a navigation controller is an easy way, if that's an acceptable architecture. Or you can use a targeted dismissal of presented controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although "current context" is not for this purpose as @matt mentioned,

You should dismiss the controller who presents this one to dismiss both together in this case:

```
self.presentingViewController!.dismiss(animated: true) // `!` is to makeing sure it's not crashing.
```

---

## Demo:

Use this simple code to demo:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func present() {
        let destination = storyboard!.instantiateInitialViewController()!
        if presentingViewController != nil {
            // You are not in the A
            if presentingViewController?.presentingViewController != nil {
                // You are in the C
                presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
                return
            } else {
                // You are in the B
                destination.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
            }
        }
        present(destination, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

## Usage:

1. Create a single view application
2. Drag a button into the view controller
3. Replace the `ViewController` class with the provided code
4. Connect the `@IBAction`
5. Run it to see the result.

Comment: Should I put this in view controller 1 or 2? I'm a bit confused

Comment: `presentingViewController` gives you the controller that presented this view. You should use this if you are in the second controller.

Comment: What I actually want is something like this:

I'm starting on A and I would like to navigate to view controller B (All I do here is picking a name) and when I got the name I would like to navigate to C. But once I've navigated to C I would like to "remove/hide" view controller B.

So all I can see should be view controller A (in the background like automatic) and C as the "current view". 

Is this possible?

Comment: I have added a simple demo that acts exactly like what you need.

Comment: I'll try it out.

Should this be implemented in view controller A, B or C?

Comment: Check my edit please. This one is placed in view controller B. And this code is returning to "login view".

How can I make it navigate to C?

Comment: I have added an instruction for it ;)

Comment: Also some comments for better understanding.

Comment: Ohhhh. It does work!

Thanks a lot for your input. I'm just so confused about this right now.

Why don't they add something like "replace" view controller. It's frustrating..

Answer (score 0):

If you use fullscreen presentation (so that there is no drag-to-dismiss) it's quite simple to do this with essentially no code at all.

[image]

Note that the yellow view controller appears as an intermediary when presenting, but not when dismissing.

Comment: I like the automatic one tho :/ but that’s a great ide!